# JQuery: fadein/fadeout effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and am hoping someone can help out with the problem I'm having.

I setup a JSFiddle Page with the issue I'm having for ease of helping me: http://jsfiddle.net/66Bwp/

The problem: When I click on the button "Test 1" or "Test 2" and then click on the black overlay that produces, the overlay disappears, however the content that was faded in stays on the page until the "cancel" button is pressed.

Interesting Side Note: If I click on the button "Test 1" or "Test 2" to produce the content effect, and then click cancel, everything works as intended (overlay and content fade out), and then if I click the button "Test 1" or "Test 2" again, without reloading the page, and then click the overlay, everything works as intended.

The Javascript File:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    lbHide();
})

function lbShow( idName ) {
    $("#lbOverlay, #" + idName).fadeIn(300);
}

function lbHide( idName ) {
    $("#lbOverlay, #" + idName).fadeOut(300);
    $("#lbOverlay").click(function() {
        $("#lbOverlay, #" + idName).fadeOut(300);
    })
}
```

The CSS File:

```
#lbOverlay{
    display:none;
    background:#000000;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
#lbExampleOne{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:400px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
    z-index:1001;
}
#lbExampleTwo{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:400px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
    z-index:1001;
}
```

The HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

        <title>Lightbox Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="show-panel" onClick="lbShow('lbExampleOne')">Test 1</button>
        <button id="show-panel" onClick="lbShow('lbExampleTwo')">Test 2</button>
        <div id="lbExampleOne">
            <h2>Example Content One</h2>
        <p><button type="reset" id="close-panel" onClick="lbHide('lbExampleOne')">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div id="lbExampleTwo">
            <h2>Example Content Two</h2>
            <p><button type="reset" id="close-panel" onClick="lbHide('lbExampleTwo')">Cancel</button></p>
        </div>
        <div id="lbOverlay"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what the problem could be. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me on chrome?

Comment: I'm using chrome, and it's not working. Please see my JSFiddle Link in my edited post. It's producing the exact error I'm having. EDIT: Make sure you are clicking Test1 and then clicking on the black overlay, NOT the cancel button first.

Comment: Side note, IDs must be unique.

Comment: I'm aware, I haven't cleaned up the code yet, wanted to get this fixed first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66Bwp/3/ - This listens for the overlay to be clicked and then triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your lbHide function to this:

```
function lbHide(idName) {
  $("#lbOverlay, #" + idName).fadeOut(300);
  $("#lbOverlay").click(function () {
    $("#lbOverlay, #lbExampleOne, #lbExampleTwo").fadeOut(300);
  })
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/66Bwp/2/)**

When your overlay is clicked, there is no `idName` parameter being passed to it, so just fade out the divs. You should probably give them classes to make them easier to refer to.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work as I need it to. I need to be able to use the idName parameter in the function dynamically for multiple boxes. It wouldn't be feasible to put every id in the javascript function when I should be able to call it dynamically from the HTML.

Comment: That's why I said to give your dialog box divs a common class.

Comment: Great idea, I just realized what you were referring to. That worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you are clicking on the overlay you are are calling the click event that you have assigned to it. The problem is that the click event uses the idName variable which has no value at this point in time.

Therefore the overlay fades but not your other elements

Comment: Ah! I get what you mean, unfortunately like I said, I am new to JQuery, can you show me an easy way to pass the idName parameter to that JQuery function so it can be used?